# Unity vector3 angles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two points on screen as follows...

```
var newraya = camera.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(200, 250, 5));
Vector3 pointa = newraya.origin;
var newrayb = camera.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(300, 200, 5));
Vector3 pointb = newrayb.origin;
```

I'm using the below formula to try getting the 90 degree angle but its calculating it as 26 degrees?

```
// angle in degrees
var angleDeg = -Mathf.Atan2(pointb.y - pointa.y, pointb.x - pointa.x) * (180 / Math.PI);
```

I'm not too sure where I'm going wrong with this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you expecting a 90 degree angle?

Comment: this is correct, you are finding the 26 degree angle. solving for the other angle gives you 64, leaving the last one as 90 (180-26-64). if you know it's 90, what is the purpose in solving for it?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PT3kf.png) image if you want a quick visualisation.

Comment: Thank you for the visualisation, now it makes sense. What efficient formula could I use to get the 90 degree angle?

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Show us the screenshot and graphic so that we can understand what you are actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the below formula which kinda worked for me. I have to wrap this in an if statement if point A is at either 0 or 90 degrees but anything in between is fine.

```
var angle34 = -(Mathf.Atan2((centre.y - ((pointa.y - centre.y))) - centre.y, (centre.x + ((centre.x - pointa.x))) - centre.x) * (180 / Math.PI))-90;
```

[image]